# Change text color on focus and have it remain that color after focus has left (onblur)

Tags: javascript, css

A CSS and perhaps Javascript question.  I want alternate rows to have different colors, the default text to be grey in color.  However, once an input field has focus I want the new text to be black and then to stay black after the field no longer has focus.  Here is what I have done so far:

```
input {
   font-family:Verdana, Trebuchet MS;
   font-size:11px;
   vertical-align:top;
}

input:focus {
    color: black;
}

input.odd {
   color: #888;
   background:#FFFFB4;
}

input.even {
   color: #888;
   background:#FFD9C8;
}
```

This code achieves my requirements of alternate rows to have different colors and the default text to be grey in color.  However, new text is grey, not black.  Then how do I get the new text to stay black.

**UPDATED CSS**

```
input {
   font-family:Verdana, Trebuchet MS;
   font-size:11px;
   vertical-align:top;
}

input.odd {
   color: #888;
   background:#FFFFB4;
}

input.even {
   color: #888;
   background:#FFD9C8;
}

input.odd:focus, input.even:focus, input.odd.hasText, input.even.hasText {
    color: black;
}
```

**NEW jQuery CODE**

```
$('input').focus(function() {
   $(this).addClass('hasText');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you want

```
input.odd:focus,input.even:focus {
    color: black;
}
```

If you mean the text reverts to grey after it loses focus, you will probably need to add a class via javascript once text is entered and have that class match your focus class.

**EDIT**

Something like:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hasText');
});
```

Then in your CSS have:

```
input.even:focus,input.odd:focus,input.hasText{
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my requirement to have the new text appear black when there is focus.  However the text changes to grey after focus has left.  Is it possible to have the text stay black even after focus has left?

Comment: I don't think so via CSS alone. But you can use javascript. I'll add an edit. I could be wrong, but I am pretty sure CSS can't determine if an input has text in it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your edit.  However the text still changes back to grey after focus has left the input text flied.

Comment: Oh you might need, `input.odd.hasText` and `input.even.hasText`. Look in Firebug to see which CSS selector is taking precedent and make sure you create one that overrides it. I'll try a JSFiddle.

Comment: This worked for me. `input.odd:focus, input.even:focus, input.odd.hasText,input.even.hasText` as a selector. http://jsfiddle.net/V8CbH/

Comment: Isn't your Javascript missing a closing bracket )

Comment: My firebug is reporting this error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

$('input').focus(function() {

Comment: My code is using jQuery. You either need to use jQuery or write what my code does using vanilla javascript which I don't know how to do.

Comment: Thanks, I've never used jQuery so I will try to convert to Javascript.

Comment: You should try it. It will save you hours of time.

Comment: Anyone care to venture a pure CSS and Javascript solution?

Comment: I have installed jQuery 1.9.1.  However, the color of the new text still changes back to grey after it loses focus.

Comment: Did you look at my jsfiddle. It's working there. So you must have some CSS that is overridding it, or you are not adding the class like you think you are.

Comment: Thanks.  When I look at the source in jsfiddle I see that it enclosed the jsQuery code within $(window).load(function(){ ... }); so I did the same with the jQuery code that you provided and voila it works.

Comment: Ahh yes, with jqueryit's best to enclose all your javascript in `$(document).ready(function(){ //ALL CODE HERE });` This makes sure the javascript is run AFTER the DOM is loaded and ready. Otherwise the javascript might try to alter elements not yet loaded in the DOM.

Comment: A related question.  Before I added this jQuery I had a pure Javascript onBlur AJAX code.  This jQuery stops the onBlur from working.  Any suggestions.  Here is the onBlur code: `function getForm() {
 if (document.getElementsByTagName) {
  var vInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (var vCount=0; vCount<vInput.length; vCount++)
   vInput[vCount].onblur = function() { return validateIt(this); }
 }
}`

Comment: I'm clueless. The jQuery equivalent of `.onblur` is simply `.blur` and in addition, jQuery shouldn't in anyway conflict with vanilla javascript. Maybe someone else can shed light on that. Is there an error popping up in the console log?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a css only solution that works if the default text (grey) is not dynamic.

```
<input class="form-item" type="text" placeholder="This is default text"/>
```

then for css:

```
//Basic input padding
        input{
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }
//styling for placeholder or default state.
    .form-item::placeholder{
      color: grey;
    }
//styling for the actual input when there is text
    .form-item {
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
    }
//styling in focus state
    .form-item:focus{
      color: red;
    }
```

This give me 3 different colors based on different states.

- Placeholder is default color.
- using class name directly is the new color.
- focus color for when the input is in focus state and I want it to look different.

In the case of the question above, I think It would also work by adding the odd and even classes.

I hope this helps :)